# How can I collect vitality restoring items like raw meat quickly and in volume?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm playing **The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt** in Death March, and I'm in sore need of goods like raw meat, dried fruit and milk.

How do I get these supplies without going through the hassle of looting individual buildings and fighting hordes of wolves?

Comment: Consider getting the Gourmet perk. All food shortages become a thing of the past.

Answer (score 8):

Vitality restoring goods like Raw Meat and Milk are essential for the higher difficulties, since meditation doesn't restore vitality.

Here is a way you can *never* run out of such goods, while making a grand profit from hides.

**Step 1**: Find a spawn location for animals like goats or deer.

**Step 2**: Move away from the exact spawn location while keeping yourself in a place from where you can properly throw a bomb.

**Step 3**: Meditate to ensure spawning of animals.

**Step 4**: Throw a bomb at the location, and collect the loot.

One such spawn location I discovered, is to the left side of Fyresdal in Skellige:

[image]

Here is a zoomed in version of the picture:

[image]

Two dozen goats spawn at once, so with **1** bomb, you should be getting about **30** pieces of raw meat and goat hides, which you can sell to a merchant for **25-35** crowns a piece.

Here are some more screenshots I captured:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just don't try to farm the cows in White Orchard... I dare you.

Comment: I agree. Complete Chort Fest.

Answer (score 4):

To save food it's better to learn Gourmet skill.

Also, you can take Ekhidna Decoction to regenerate 10% of HP for each sign used.